# How to extract 7z file with python in Ubuntu environment?

Tags: python, ubuntu, extract, 7zip

I want to extract .7z file using python.
Previously in Windows I use `pyunpack` to extract it, and works. But when I run my script on Ubuntu, It return an error during extraction.
This is the error:

```
pyunpack.PatoolError: patool can not unpack
patool error: error extracting file.7z: could not find an executable program to extract format 7z
```

This is my code to extract it:

```
from pyunpack import Archive

Archive(C:\folder\file.7z).extractall(C:\output_folder)
```

Anyone can help me please. Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure you ran all the [installation commands](https://github.com/ponty/pyunpack/tree/0.2.2#installation-on-ubuntu)?

Comment: Hi @ox263A, I just install this `$ sudo apt-get install unzip unrar p7zip-full` the other two are installed. But it still return error `pyunpack.PatoolError: patool can not unpack, ERROR: file.7z can not open the file as [7z] archive`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you should check if you can run `7z` in linux console

Comment: I have no problem to use `pyunpack` to extract from `file.7z` on `Linux Mint`. And I have no problem to run `7z` directly in system console. And command `which 7z` shows full path `/usr/bin/7z` so it is in folder with other programs. If you can't run `7z` in system console then it can have problem to use it in `pyunpack`

Comment: It works now, I restart the system, then it works. Thanks all :)